# Como evitar que conteúdo de uma div rotacione junto com o efeito rotate do css?

Tags: css, html5, front-end

Bom dia a todos.

Coloquei o efeito de rotate em uma div, mas o conteúdo interno também girou junto. Como faço para ele ficar normal com alinhamento padrão e a div continuar com o rotate?

exemplo:

`.minha-div{-webkit-transform:scale(1.5) rotate(5deg);}`

Com esse feito a div gira 5 graus. Mas o conteúdo gira junto.

Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Por favor, faça um [mcve] demonstrando o problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta colocar uma rotação negativa na *div* do conteúdo, no seu caso seria `-5deg`.

```css
.minha-div {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5) rotate(5deg);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 100px;
  }
  
 .conteudo {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="minha-div">
<div class="conteudo">teste</div>
</div>
```

Como o *lazyFox* mencionou nos comentários, também existe uma forma de fazer isso utilizando o atributo `:after`. Acho o método anterior mais simplificado, mas fica aqui para curiosidade:

```css
.minha-div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 100px;
}
.minha-div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index:-1;
}

.conteudo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="minha-div">
    <div class="conteudo">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Existe uma solução usando `:after` `:before` no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9513671/1473534), interessante.

Comment: Excelente. Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado mesmo amigo. Valeu!